# Ckeditor4-vue with Nuxt.js how to access CKEDITOR

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, ckeditor4.x

I have started using ckeditor4-vue

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_vue.html#using-the-component-locally

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ckeditor
      v-model="formData"
      :config="editorConfig"
      @input="$emit('update:editorData', formData)"
    ></ckeditor>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CKEditor from 'ckeditor4-vue';

export default {
  components: {
    ckeditor: CKEditor.component
  },
  props: ['editorData'],
  data() {
    return {
      formData: this.editorData,
      editorConfig: {}
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
  }
};
</script>
```

However I can't find how I can use CKEDITOR, in this example, I have CKEDITOR is not defined.

Thank you

Comment: Man, recentlly i'm started with the CKEDITOR, and after some days I gaveup, because this package does't works aproprietlly in my project. I don't know why. But after tests in many others packages, finalIy found one package called tiptap. This was the best thing I have make in my live, This works like a charm and is a most powerfull, and better is you don't have any bugs to solve.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're calling it the right way, CKEDITOR <> CKEditor.
try removing your mounted and this should works